# Shall, third person singular, archaic form

Tags: future, archaicisms, conjugation

The second person of *will* and *shall* are *wilt* and *shalt* in the archaic form. The third person singular suffix is *-eth*, so we get *willeth* but what about *shall*?

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Willeth* is used as a transitive verb ("La Reine le veult," "The Queen wills it", as Parliament has the Royal Assent).

We don't get *willeth* for *will* as a modal auxiliary indicating future action. These verbs don't change; similarly *shall* and *must* don't change either.

Comment: In fact, all the modal auxiliaries do not change for person, except, archaically, for the second singular.

Comment: @ColinFine Since the topic is about the archaic language, I thank you for that detail.